# Differentiability of Norm $N: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n i|x_i|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

> **Problem**: Let $U:= \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \neq 0 \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq n \rbrace  $ and show that the Norm given by $$ N: \begin{cases} U & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ x & \longmapsto \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i\vert x_i \vert \end{cases} $$
>   is differentiable on $U$ but $N$ is not differentiable at $0$

**My Approach P1**: I first tackled the easier part (in my opinion). I know that if $N$ is differentiable at $0$ then all directional derivatives at that point exist, thus I considered to use the contra positive of that statement.

Let $h$ be any direction and then consider the following $$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x_i}(0)= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{N(0+h)-N(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i |h|-0}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{n|h|}{h} $$
Which shows that the limit does not exists, it depends on the direction of $h$ and therefore the directional derivative does not exist at $0$. Can you comment please *(in comments or in your answer)* if this approach was correct?

---

**P2:** Now to show that $N$ is differentiable on $U$ I am a bit stuck, should I try to compute the Jacobi-Matrix? (I kind of dislike doing that because it feels very artificial to me) Or can I try to compute $$\lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} \frac{N(x+h \epsilon)-N(x)}{\epsilon}= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\sum i|x_i + \epsilon h|-\sum i |x_i|}{\epsilon} \leq n |h| $$
Which shows that the limit is bound by a constant independent of the actual direction (just by the magnitude). I believe I miss some accurate reasoning here in this step.

---

I often try showing that a function is differentiable by using the actual definition  of differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which forces me to find a linear mapping, but I don't succeed with that.

Comment: Your approach to the first part is correct, but maybe you could show more explicitly that the limit doesn't exist. For the second part, show that the partial derivatives exist (which is kind of obvious) and are continuous if $x\neq0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @VincentBoelens, do you mean by showing more explicitly that the limit does not exist by letting $h$ approach $0$ from the positive and the negative and showing that the two limits differ? For the 2nd part I am still lost, I agree that the partial derivatives exists and are continuous, so you recommend me computing the Jacobi matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. For the 2nd part, you are done. If the partial derivatives exist and are continuous, the function is continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove differentiability on $U$, pick a point $x\in U$. Let $\sigma_i = x_i/|x_i|$ for each $i$; this is either $1$ or $-1$, i.e., the sign of $x_i$. Note that if $h\in\mathbb R$ is sufficiently small, then the coordinates of $x+h$ have the same signs as the coordinates of $x$. More precisely, let $r=\min |x_i|$. If $h$ satisfies $\max |h_i| <r $, then $\operatorname{sign}(x_i+h_i)=\operatorname{sign} x_i$ for all $i$. All this long-winded setup is to show that in a neighborhood of $x$, the norm $N$ is a **linear** function, namely 
$$N(x+h) = \sum_{i} i \sigma_i (x_i+h_i)$$ Clearly, the linear function is differentiable.

As for non-differentiability at $0$: the non-existence of the partial $\partial N/\partial x_1$, shown in your post, settles the issue.